# Get JSF managed bean by name in any Servlet related class

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, servlets, jsf-2, managed-bean

I'm trying to write a custom servlet (for AJAX/JSON) in which I would like to reference my `@ManagedBeans` by name. I'm hoping to map:

`http://host/app/myBean/myProperty`

to:

```
@ManagedBean(name="myBean")
public class MyBean {
    public String getMyProperty();
}
```

Is it possible to load a bean by name from a regular servlet? Is there a JSF servlet or helper I could use for it?

I seem to be spoilt by Spring in which all this is too obvious.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can use these new annotations outside JSF/EL, but I'd start by looking at the JSR 299 spec: http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=299

Comment: Other people having problems with similar issues can also check https://bpcatalog.dev.java.net/ajax/jsf-ajax/ (related to AJAX and request mapping/handling, not getting beans by name)

Answer (score 272, accepted):

In a servlet based artifact, such as `@WebServlet`, `@WebFilter` and `@WebListener`, you can grab a "plain vanilla" JSF `@ManagedBean @RequestScoped` by:

```
Bean bean = (Bean) request.getAttribute("beanName");
```

and `@ManagedBean @SessionScoped` by:

```
Bean bean = (Bean) request.getSession().getAttribute("beanName");
```

and `@ManagedBean @ApplicationScoped` by:

```
Bean bean = (Bean) getServletContext().getAttribute("beanName");
```

Note that this prerequires that the bean is already autocreated by JSF beforehand. Else these will return `null`. You'd then need to manually create the bean and use `setAttribute("beanName", bean)`.

---

If you're able to use CDI [`@Named`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/inject/Named.html) instead of the since JSF 2.3 deprecated `@ManagedBean`, then it's even more easy, particularly because you don't anymore need to manually create the beans:

```
@Inject
private Bean bean;
```

Note that this won't work when you're using `@Named @ViewScoped` because the bean can only be identified by JSF view state and that's only available when the `FacesServlet` has been invoked. So in a filter which runs before that, accessing an `@Inject`ed `@ViewScoped` will always throw `ContextNotActiveException`.

---

Only when you're inside `@ManagedBean`, then you can use [`@ManagedProperty`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/faces/bean/ManagedProperty.html):

```
@ManagedProperty("#{bean}")
private Bean bean;
```

Note that this doesn't work inside a `@Named` or `@WebServlet` or any other artifact. It really works inside `@ManagedBean` only.

---

If you're not inside a `@ManagedBean`, but the `FacesContext` is readily available (i.e. `FacesContext#getCurrentInstance()` doesn't return `null`), you can also use [`Application#evaluateExpressionGet()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/faces/application/Application.html#evaluateExpressionGet-javax.faces.context.FacesContext-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-):

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Bean bean = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{beanName}", Bean.class);
```

which can be convenienced as follows:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T findBean(String beanName) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    return (T) context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{" + beanName + "}", Object.class);
}
```

and can be used as follows:

```
Bean bean = findBean("bean");
```

---

#### See also:

- [Backing beans (@ManagedBean) or CDI Beans (@Named)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347374/backing-beans-managedbean-or-cdi-beans-named)

Comment: You're second suggestion about just injecting the bean was so amazingly simple I had totally overlooked it.  As always, your response is perfectly to the point.  Thanks so much for your work here on SO.

Comment: In the meantime (speaking as of JSF 2.2) it seems like the method evaluateExpressionGet was extended with a third parameter that allows to specify the expected class so casting won't be necessary anymore.

``PostBean bean = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{beanName}", PostBean.class);``

Comment: @Marc: Has been in from the beginning. Was just a leftover from a copypaste mistake I guess. Answer has been corrected. Thank you for notifying.

Comment: `FacesContext` is available even though the `static` utility method `findBean()` is defined inside a plain Java class. How is it available there in a plain Java class which is not managed by JSF?

Comment: @Tiny: it's in turn called by a JSF artifact within the same thread.

Comment: Hi I get  FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); context=null why??   and  Trying  to use HttpServletRequest request like this       Bean bean = (Bean) request.getSession().getAttribute("ingresoSistema"); I got this: Servlet.service() for servlet servletsimple threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed. My bean: @ManagedBean(name = "ingresoSistema")
@SessionScoped

Comment: @BalusC I was expecting `findBean(String beanName)` to be available in http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/Beans, but it's not. Is there any reason for that (other than keeping it strictly CDI)?

Comment: @Jasper: You can use `Faces#evaluateExpressionGet()` for this.

Comment: @BalusC OK, but you would still have to use `"#{" + beanName + "}"`, right? Or am I being lazy here? ;-)

Answer (score 11):

I use the following method:

```
public static <T> T getBean(final String beanName, final Class<T> clazz) {
    ELContext elContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext();
    return (T) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getELResolver().getValue(elContext, null, beanName);
}
```

This allows me to get the returned object in a typed manner.

Comment: This is already covered by the currently accepted answer and even in a more convenient way (`Class` argument is namely unnecessary in this construct).

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried an approach like on this link? I'm not sure if `createValueBinding()` is still available but code like this should be accessible from a plain old Servlet. This does require to bean to already exist.

http://www.coderanch.com/t/211706/JSF/java/access-managed-bean-JSF-from

```
 FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();  
 Application app = context.getApplication();
 // May be deprecated
 ValueBinding binding = app.createValueBinding("#{" + expr + "}"); 
 Object value = binding.getValue(context);
```

Comment: This probably won't work in a regular servlet. The FacesContext is a per-request thread-local artefact set up by the JSF lifecycle (usually the FacesServlet).

Comment: ValueBinding is deprecated since JSF 1.2 over 4 years ago.

Comment: @BalusC: It shows how up to date I am lol. On a sidenote, using a search engine to research techniques is turning out to be counterproductive with all the old information out there.
@McDowell: That actually makes sense. I'll do a test just to see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the managed bean by passing the name:

```
public static Object getBean(String beanName){
    Object bean = null;
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    if(fc!=null){
         ELContext elContext = fc.getELContext();
         bean = elContext.getELResolver().getValue(elContext, null, beanName);
    }

    return bean;
}
```

Comment: I try to to this  from a servlet  but it doesn`t work.

Comment: What if I am inside a Quartz Job and I don´t have FacesContext available? How can I get a Managed Bean from the application context?

Answer (score 0):

I had same requirement.

I have used the below way to get it.

I had session scoped bean.

```
@ManagedBean(name="mb")
@SessionScopedpublic 
class ManagedBean {
     --------
}
```

I have used the below code in my servlet doPost() method.

```
ManagedBean mb = (ManagedBean) request.getSession().getAttribute("mb");
```

it solved my problem.

Comment: What kind of servlet do you use? mate

Comment: It is HttpServlet.

Answer (score -1):

I use this:

```
public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> clazz) {
    try {
        String beanName = getBeanName(clazz);
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        return facesContext.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(facesContext, "#{" + beanName + "}", clazz);
    //return facesContext.getApplication().getELResolver().getValue(facesContext.getELContext(), null, nomeBean);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}

public static <T> String getBeanName(Class<T> clazz) {
    ManagedBean managedBean = clazz.getAnnotation(ManagedBean.class);
    String beanName = managedBean.name();

    if (StringHelper.isNullOrEmpty(beanName)) {
        beanName = clazz.getSimpleName();
        beanName = Character.toLowerCase(beanName.charAt(0)) + beanName.substring(1);
    }

    return beanName;
}
```

And then call:

```
MyManageBean bean = getBean(MyManageBean.class);
```

This way you can refactor your code and track usages without problems.