# Java to get an instance of ManagedBean By its name

Tags: jsf

How to get an instance of a managed bean whose scope is request in JSF??

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSF - get managed bean by name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633112/jsf-get-managed-bean-by-name)

Answer (score 2):

For jsf 1.2 I use in code next expression:

```
    MyBean identifier =  (MyBean) context.getApplication().getELResolver().getValue(context.getELContext(), null, "myRequiredBean");
```

where "myRequiredBean" - beans defenition in faces-config.xml

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify a specific name in the `@ManagedBean(name = "name")` annotations `name` attribute, the name defaults to the class' name with it's first letter lowercased. Same thing if you use JSF <2.0, but it uses xml instead of annotations.

You can get anything you need from that managed bean then using EL, which in JSF is `#{beanName.field}`.
If using EL 2.2+, you can call a method with `#{beanName.method('param')}`.

Also, for the future -- you really should specify the JSF version and containers that you run it in.