# Richfaces: call multiple methods in s:link's action attribute

Tags: java, xhtml, richfaces

Currently I have:

```
action="#{A.actionA() &amp;&amp; B.ActionB()}"
```

But I get the error:

```
Not a Valid Method Expression: #{A.actionA() &amp;&amp; B.ActionB()}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK , the EL expression does not allow calling several methods in one expression.

I suggest you can wrap these two functions to a new function and then call this new function instead.

For example  ,

```
action="#{bean.onPressLink()}"
```

And the `onPressLink()` will call `A.actionA()` and `B.actionB()`

```
public void onPressLink(){
     //Get the managed bean called A and then call its actionA();
     //Get the managed bean called B and then call its actionB();
}
```

To get the managed bean by its name , you can refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633112/jsf-get-managed-bean-by-name).