# JSF2 ApplicationScope bean instantiation time?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

It seems to me, that `@ApplicationScoped` beans are initiated only the first time they are accessed in a page using EL.

When I query the `ApplicationMap`, will the `@ApplicationScoped` bean be created?

```
ExternalContext ec = currentInstance.getExternalContext(); result =
    ec.getApplicationMap().get(beanName);
```

How else could I trigger the instantiation of the application scoped bean before an XHTML page has been loaded?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `eager=true` in the [`@ManagedBean`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedBean.html) declaration.

```
@ManagedBean(eager=true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class Config {

    // ...

}
```

This way the bean will be autocreated on webapp's startup.

Instead of that, you could also use [`Application#evaluateExpressionGet()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html#evaluateExpressionGet%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29) to programmatically evaluate EL and so auto-create the bean if necessary. See also the example on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633112/jsf-get-managed-bean-by-name/2633733#2633733).

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Confic config = (Config) context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{config}", Config.class);
// ...
```

You could also just inject it as a [`@ManagedProperty`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedProperty.html) of the bean where you need it.

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Register {

    @ManagedProperty("#{config}")
    private Config config;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

JSF will auto-create it before injecting in the parent bean. It's available in all methods beyond `@PostConstruct`.