# Java Inject Applicationscope Bean

Tags: jakarta-ee, scope, ejb, javabeans, inject

I try to inject a applicationScoped Bean. 
I found similar topics at [JSF2 ApplicationScope bean instantiation time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967182/jsf2-applicationscope-bean-instantiation-time) and
[Get JSF managed bean by name in any Servlet related class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633112/jsf-get-managed-bean-by-name)

With the jsf way in faces context all is fine (WebsitesController is AppScoped):

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
WebsiteController websitesController = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{websitesController}", WebsitesController.class);
```

With the injections of the two overflow threads it doesn't work. My Code:

```
@ManagedBean(eager=true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class WebsitesController implements Serializable {
...}
```

and now i tried

```
@ManagedBean(name = "shopController")
@ViewScoped
public class ShopController {
    {Injection-Statement}
    private WebsitesController websitesController;
```

I tried following statements:

```
@ManagedProperty("#{websitesController}")
@Inject
@EJB
```

Whats my fault?

Answer (score 1):

I have also a problem with ApplicationScope on Glassfish. Do you have an maven or ant webproject? (With maven i think the ApplicationScope doesn´t work as expected - with ant it does)

Now to your question:

When you use @Inject, then your WebsiteController need @Named and @ApplicationScope (other imports as jsf !!) and you must have an beans.xml - then CDI is activated.

When you use @ EJB, then yout WebsiteController need @Stateless .

I hope i can help you...