# Is it not possible to access a managed property inside a non managed bean class?

Tags: jsf

Is it not possible to access a managed property inside a non managed bean class by using `@ManagedProperty(value="#{beanName}")`?

I am getting a `NullPointerException` while trying to do that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure that bean is alive when you are accessing its property [you can fetch it from `FacesContext`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633112/jsf-get-managed-bean-by-name) and access its property, but you can't inject a managed bean as property in a normal Java class.