# When, exactly, @Inject annotation initiates injection of SessionScoped bean in Servlet?

Tags: servlets, jsf-2, cdi

I need to modify a user session object (SessionScoped bean - CDI) in a Servlet, so I have to obtain that bean somehow. I used injection in the following way:

```
@Inject
private UserSession user;
```

where UserSession is the SessionScoped CDI bean. *user* methods are called from either doPost or doGet servlet methods.
This works perfectly; every time the @Inject annotation injects the appropriate UserSession bean, but I don't understand **how** this behavior is achieved.

I assumed that the beans, annotated with @Inject, are injected only once (when the object - Servlet instance in this case - is created), but it is obviously a wrong presumption.

So, when are these beans injected into the servlet? Per request? And how does this approach avoids conflicts (one servlet instance - multiple threads to deal with it) when there are multiple UserSession objects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The CDI uses the [proxy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern). The injected instance is actually not the real instance, but a proxy which locates the real instance depending on the current context and delegates all methods to it (like as how EJBs work). The autogenerated class of your `UserSession` bean looks roughly like this:

```
public UserSessionCDIProxy extends UserSession implements Serializable {

    public String getSomeProperty() {
        UserSession instance = CDI.resolveItSomehow();
        return instance.getSomeProperty();
    }

    public void setSomeProperty(String someProperty) {
        UserSession instance = CDI.resolveItSomehow();
        instance.setSomeProperty(someProperty);
    }

}
```

This mechanism allows you to inject instances of a narrower scope in instances of a broader scope and allows you to still get the expected instance in the current context. The standard JSF `@ManagedProperty` annotation doesn't support it, simply because it does not use a proxy, but injects the desired instance directly. That's why it's not possible to inject something of a narrower scope by `@ManagedProperty`.

#### See also:

- [Backing beans (@ManagedBean) or CDI Beans (@Named)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347374/backing-beans-managedbean-or-cdi-beans-named/4347707#4347707)
- [Get JSF managed bean by name in any Servlet related class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633112/get-jsf-managed-bean-by-name-in-any-servlet-related-class)
- [When using @EJB, does each managed bean get its own @EJB instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25514361/when-using-ejb-does-each-managed-bean-get-its-own-ejb-instance/)
- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope)

Answer (score 4):

Your answer lies in the C of CDI, which stands for Contexts.

What happens is that not the actual bean is injected, but a proxy. This proxy is contextual and resolves to the actual session scoped bean depending on the context of the caller on who's behalf the proxy is executed.