# Why EJB's constructor called twice in a @RequestScoped bean?

Tags: jsf, ejb

I have an EJB bean injected in a Managed Bean. Its constructor is called twice. 
For example, I get:

```
com.logic.jsf.AdditionManagedBean created
com.logic.Addition$$$view45 created
com.logic.Addition created
```

I know @PostConstruct but I'm trying to understand why that happens. Is it because of proxy, and in that case shouldn't I see a proxy related literal in the printed name of the class?

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean 
public class Addition{  
        public Addition(){
            System.out.println(this.getClass().getName() +" created");
        }


        public String getAddition(){
            return "Addition";
        }
}
```

Injected in:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class AdditionManagedBean {

    @EJB
    Addition addition;

    public AdditionManagedBean(){
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getName()+" created");
    }

    public String getAddition(){
        return addition.getAddition();
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Is it because of proxy"* Yes. *"and in that case shouldn't I see a proxy related literal?"* What?

Comment: Anyway, this is related/duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25514361

Comment: Shouldn't the name of the class that is printed be related to "proxy" instead of "view"?

Comment: Why do you think that it's not a proxy?