# Overridden toString method in EJB not invoked

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, tostring

I am studying/experimenting with EJBs. I have an EJB with an overridden toString method:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class FlightService {
... 
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "FlightService [id=" + id + ", from=" + from + ", to=" + to + ", price=" + price + ", airplaneModel="
            + airplaneModel + "]";
}
```

}

In my servlet, I inject this EJB into a variable, like this:

```
@EJB
private FlightService fs;
```

However, when I would like to print it out..

```
if (fs != null){
    out.println("Flight details: " + fs.toString());
}
```

.. I get the following output, which is what I would get with the defaul toString method, I think.

```
Flight details: com.airline.service.__EJB31_Generated__FlightService__Intf___754270295
```

Instead of

```
Flight details: FlightService [id=123, ...]
```

as I would expect. All other functionalities of the EJB are working as expected, as far as I can tell. Can someone please explain to me what happens with the toString method? Thank you!

EDIT: It works with explicitly created objects (new FlightService()), as suggested by Soumitri Pattnaik.

EDIT2: Full source available on pastebin. [FlightService.java](http://pastebin.com/WHc9a7g3), [FlightDetails.java](http://pastebin.com/pSB6Q1pK)
The project was created in Eclipse, running on Glassfish 4.

Comment: what type are the elements you are trying to print? also, you don't have to put fs.toString(), when putting fs in a print statement, it will automatically call the toString method

Comment: Check the type of the actual `fs` object, it may be of some other class or interface. And that might be the reason of different `toString()` call.

Comment: @Stultuske They are just some local int and String variables I handle with getters and setters.
"it will automatically call the toString method", thanks, I wasn't sure about that. I get the same result, though.

Comment: @Soumitri Pattnaik It is of the type FlightService, which I think is what it should be.

Comment: @b4kancs as you are not explicitly creating the object by `new` keyword, there is a chance that, the actual object is of a child  / parent type.

Comment: @Soumitri Pattnaik I see. I thought I wasn't supposed to do that with EJBs. I also tried to look it up through JNDI with the same results. I will try some things now.

Comment: @b4kancs good luck buddy

Comment: @Soumitri Pattnaik It indeed works with a new FlightService() object. I will try to find out what happens in the background now. Thanks!

Comment: In the future, please don't use [java] tag as long as problem is not reproducible with a plain Java application class with `main()` method. You'll otherwise get a lot of noise, blind guesses and possibly completely wrong answers from those [java] users.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks, got it!

Comment: Your EJB toString method is fundamentally flawed anyway. Your EJB is annotated @Stateless, therefore your toString method may be called on a different instance of the bean than the one that has the state that you specified.

Comment: @SteveC Yeah, I got that. I was just experimenting. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@EJB` doesn't inject an actual instance. `@EJB` injects an autogenerated proxy instance which locates the actual instance in the pool and delegates to it. Depending on the EJB implementation used (read: depending on the appserver used), the autogenerated proxy class may have its own `toString()` which may or may not use your `toString()`. Yours apparently completely ignores it.

#### See also:

- [When using @EJB, does each managed bean get its own @EJB instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25514361/when-using-ejb-does-each-managed-bean-get-its-own-ejb-instance/)

Comment: "an autogenerated proxy instance" - I didn't know about this part, thanks! It's much clearer now.

Comment: The client just uses the proxy with the implemented interface to communicate with the container, not the concrete implementation class. And then the container calls the concrete instance within the prepared context (security, transaction, etc)

Comment: @TheBitman: indeed, see also the "See also" link for a concrete example.