# Why does the @PostConstruct method not get called using BeanManager.getReference() to obtain an instance?

Tags: jsf-2, seam, cdi

We are currently moving from JSF-ManagedBeans to CDI. Unfortunately we have made excessive use of the EL-Resolver in the past in order to gain static access to session scoped beans managed by JSF.

Since CDI dependency injection is not available everywhere I rewrote the existing static lookup to make use of the `BeanManager` (Using SEAM-Solder extending `BeanManagerAware`).

```
Iterator<Bean<?>> iterator = beans.iterator();
Bean<T> bean = (Bean<T>) iterator.next(); // possible NPE, I know :)

CreationalContext<T> creationalContext = beanManager.createCreationalContext(bean);
T contextual = (T) beanManager.getReference(bean, type, creationalContext);

return contextual;
```

The code works and returns a container managed instance of the desired bean. **BUT:** the methods annotated with `@PostConstruct` do not get called using `getReference()`. Perhaps you guys know how to do it. Couldn't find anything googling the issue :-/

Best regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using [`Application#evaluateExpressionGet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html#evaluateExpressionGet%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29) for this. Not only for CDI beans, but actually also for JSF beans you previously had.

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Bean bean = (Bean) context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{beanName}", Bean.class);
// ...
```

Much cleaner, however, is to just use CDI's [`@Inject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Inject.html) or JSF's [`@ManagedProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedProperty.html) instead.

#### See also:

- [Get JSF managed bean by name in any Servlet related class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633112/jsf-get-managed-bean-by-name/)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @BalusC, I really appreciate your help. We would use `@Inject` but we need access within classes that are not pulled up by the container (ResourceResolver). I've tried using `evaluateExpressionGet()` and I do receive an instance of the managed bean, but the method annotated with `@PostConstruct`does not get called, too. When I include the bean within a facelet like `#{myBean.someValue}` the `@PostConstruct` method gets called. Guess I'll have to rollback to JSF's `@ManagedBean` annotations, so we can still use the constructor to initialize the beans. Thanks anyways!