# how to get beans from view scope

Tags: jsf-2

I want to ask if i place my managed bean in session scope, then it is stored in session' Like if i have a bean like this

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class SessionScopedBean implements Serializable {

    .......

} //end of class SessionScopedBean
```

Then it stored in the session, and during my session i can get it using

```
session.getAttribut("SessionScopedBean");
```

This will give me the SessionScopedBean Object, and when session will get destroy, i will get null. Now i want to ask if i have my bean in view Scope, then how can i get it. Like

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ViewScopedBean implements Serializable {

    .......

} //end of class ViewScopedBean
```

Now if the view is persist then this bean is in the view state, and when view changes, this bean will get destroy.Now i want to ask how can i get this bean from view state,  if the view persist. Like

```
view.getAttrubute("ViewScopedBean");  //just a code. No actual implementation.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

They're stored in the view map as available by [`UIViewRoot#getViewMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIViewRoot.html#getViewMap%28%29):

```
Map<String, Object> viewMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewMap();
ViewScopedBean viewScopedBean = (ViewScopedBean) viewMap.get("viewScopedBean");
// ...
```

Equivalently, you should be using the session map abstraction as well which is available by [`ExternalContext#getSessionMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getSessionMap%28%29) (you ultimately want to have **zero** `javax.servlet` import declarations throughout your JSF code):

```
Map<String, Object> sessionMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap();
SessionScopedBean sessionScopedBean = (SessionScopedBean) sessionMap.get("sessionScopedBean");
// ...
```

#### See also:

- [Get JSF managed bean by name in any Servlet related class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633112/jsf-get-managed-bean-by-name)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, this may not be the best way. Look at [`@ManagedProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedProperty.html) if possible.

Comment: Is the parameter to the viewMap `viewMap.get("viewScopedBean");` an EL name? Is this only working for JSF-managed beans? If so, how do I get CDI-managed, view-scoped beans (Seam 3)? -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42008956/how-do-you-find-cdi-beans-of-in-the-current-view-scope