# How to access @ViewScoped managed beans from Servlets?

Tags: jsf, servlets, view-scope

I would like to access a view scope managed bean inside a Servlet.

I searched for similar question and got these ones:

[how to get beans from view scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172737/how-to-get-beans-from-view-scope) which uses `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()`, inapplicable inside a Servlet because it should give a null result

[JSF - get managed bean by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633112/jsf-get-managed-bean-by-name) which treats all other scopes but not viewscope

I'm going to think it is not possible, is it ?

There is the simple solution to change that bean scope to session scope but it is a last chance because I'm worried by memory consumption.

My final need is the following: the managebean contains some data displayed in a dataTable. The same page should include the image (mandatory) of chart representation of those data. The image can be produced by a Servlet but it needs to access the data or reload them from the db.

I also tried the `<p:graphicImage>` from PrimeFaces 2.X but it is not compatible with viewscope beans. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not possible, no. The view scope is tied to a specific JSF view, which is no means of in a plain HTTP servlet request. Note that you can't access concrete request scoped beans during a plain HTTP servlet request either, they would always return `null`.

The session scope is the best what you can get. You can just remove the attribute from the session scope once you're finished with it in the servlet.

```
session.removeAttribute("somename");
```

Comment: Wherever I have a JSF related question I know I can count on you. Thanks

Comment: >BalusC said: "Note that you can't access concrete request scoped beans during a plain HTTP servlet request either..."  Could you please explain why?  Thanks.

Comment: @JMS: simple, it isn't the same HTTP request as the one used for the JSF page ...