# How to get my managed beans by name in JSF?

Tags: java, jsf, servlets, jsf-2

I have been working on writing a servlet for AJAX/JSON.

I want to reference my @ManagedBeans by name. I basically want to do the mapping between:

```
http://host/app/myBeanName/myPropertyName
```

and-

```
@ManagedBean(name="myBeanName")
public class MyBeanName {
    public String getMyProperty();
}
```

Can I load a bean by name from a regular servlet? Or if there is a JSF servlet or helper I could use for it please tell me about it?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Well you could write a servlet, which would return a bean or its property from the context?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSF - get managed bean by name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633112/jsf-get-managed-bean-by-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I load a bean by name from a regular servlet? O

Yes if you have your bean in request scope then from servlet `@RequestScope`

```
YourBean bean = (YourBean)request.getAttribute("yourBeanName");
```

if it is in session scope `@SessionScoped`

```
YourBean bean = (YourBean)request.getSession().getAttribute("yourBeanName");
```

for application scoped bean `@ApplicationScope`

```
YourBean bean = (YourBean)getServletContext().getAttribute("yourBeanName");
```