# What is the relation between session scoped beans and HttpServletRequest?

Tags: jsf, javabeans, httprequest

While trying to figure out how to implement a login filter for a JSF app I saw these 2 lines of code that I didn't understand that much :

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {  

HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
LoginBean login = (LoginBean) req.getSession().getAttribute("login");

}
```

Assuming that LoginBean class is a session scoped bean named "login" , as I noticed the bean is an attribute for the request , what is the relation between them ? are all session scoped bean saved as "attributes" in request sessions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *are all session scoped bean saved as "attributes" in request sessions ?*

That's correct. JSF is just a MVC framework which is built on top of the bare Servlet API, not an entirely standalone framework which can run without the Servlet API. Even more, the JSF core controller `FacesServlet` is a fullworthy `Servlet`, so it definitely requires a servlet container to run. The concept "session" is in the Servlet API provided by `HttpSession`, so it would make fully sense to store JSF session scoped beans in there instead of reinventing it.

Note that JSF request scoped beans are stored as `HttpServletRequest` attributes and that JSF application scoped beans are stored as `ServletContext` attributes.

#### See also:

- [Get JSF managed bean by name in any Servlet related class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633112/jsf-get-managed-bean-by-name/)
- [How do servlets work? Instantiation, sessions, shared variables and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-session-variables-and-multithreading)