# Accessing FacesContext in servlet

Tags: jsf, servlets

I'm working on a JSF (v1.2) application. In my application I need a generic servlet which could serve any resource (PDF, Images, Excel, etc). My idea is to ask the caller to send the required information so that I can find out the correct delegator class using some configurations.

This delegator class will take care of serving the correct resource.

For example this is the request url

```
http://example.com/servlet?delegatorid=abcd
```

My Servlet code is something like this.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
 String delegatorID=request.getParameter("delegatorid");
//Get the configuration from Configuration table
configuration=getConfiguration(delegatorID);
//invoke the method of the delegator class based on this configuration
Object result=invokeMethod(configuration);
//write the response to the stream
}
```

My question is what is the best way to do this in a JSF project?

1. Should I completely avoid JSF dependency in this operation? I can find the delegator method and class and invoke it using reflection. Will there be any potential restrictions in future if I avoid JSF dependency. [One problem which I can think about is, in one of the code, I need to get the user information from session. I'm doing this through FacesContext. Since FacesContext is not available, it will fail, I should have another option to get the session.
2. If I have to introduce JSF dependency, how do I get the FacesContext
   here? As far as I know, only the beans that are stored in
   application scope can be accessed here. I don't want to do that. Is there any other way of getting it?
3. Instead of using a servlet, can I do this by invoking a ManagedBean
   method directly using the URL? This will give me FacesContext. I
   think I need to have a dummy JSP page for the managed bean method to
   get invoked.

Could you please let me your thoughts on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `FacesContext` (and `ExternalContext`) is just a [facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) over `HttpServletRequest`, `HttpServletResponse`, `HttpSession`, `ServletContext`, etcetara along with some JSF specifics which you don't need at all in a plain vanilla servlet. The `ExternalContext#getSessionMap()` is nothing more than an abstract mapping of `HttpSession#get/setAttribute()`.

In a plain vanilla servlet, the session is just available by `request.getSession()` and the application by `getServletContext()` the usual way. See also among others this related question: [Get JSF managed bean by name in any Servlet related class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633112/jsf-get-managed-bean-by-name).

You can also just refactor code which needs to be shared by JSF and Servlet into an utility method which doesn't have any dependencies on `javax.faces.*` nor `javax.servlet.*` classes (or at most only `javax.servlet.*`) and finally let the callers each pass the necessary information through.

Comment: Thanks BalusC for the response. Regarding the last point, could you please provide me a sample for this? For example if there is a code that get the userInfoFromSession(), is it better not to pass any parameter, rather get the Session information from FacesContext if it exists or from HttpServletRequest (using ThreadLocal) ?

Comment: Well, an utility method would be exaggerated. In JSF it's just `sessionMap.get("user")` and in servlet it's just `session.getAttribute("user")`. Those oneliners aren't exactly worth a generic helper method.

Comment: Hi BalusC, Is it a good approach to get he current HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse from Threadlocal variable? What I'm thinking is there will be a generic method called getUserInfoFromSession(), which will get the information of the user from Session. Will use FacesContext to get the session, if it doesn't exist, I assume that it is from a servlet directly and try to get the HttpServletRequest from the ThreadLocal variable. Could you please suggest?