# Using jquery ajax to call a jsf managed bean method (an AjaxBehaviorEvent listener handler)

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf, managed-bean

i would like to know if there is a way to fire a jsf managed bean method (with an AjaxBehaviorEvent type parameter: the same triggered when using f:ajax) directly by using a jquery ajax server request.By the way , i m a jsf developper and i didn't find an example about using jquery ajax with Java EE as a server-side framework, all examples i found were with php..so i wish to get a complete example about doing that. 
i think the other workaround maybe is to make a commandLink being submitted with jquery on the client side and passing parameters through that call but i prefer the former solution and i wish it work.

Thanks very much for help !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    doAwesomeness();

</script>
```

In your page:

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="doAwesomeness" action="#{awesomeBean.awesomeMethod}"/>
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thnx awesome stackoverflow member :)

Comment: But this is not pure JSF. The tag comes from [RichFaces](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_jsFunction.html).

Answer (score 6):

jQuery ajax request and JSF ajax request uses different js library's , I don't think there is a point in trying to mix those to too much...

If you whish to fire a JSF managed bean action from jQuery you better use a hidden `h:commandButton` for that purpose...

JSF:

```
<h:commandButton id="someId" action="#{someBean.someMethod}" style="display:none">
    <f:ajax render="someId" execute="someId"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

if you want to pass some more hidden args you can add some more hidden JSF components ids in the hidden `h:commandButton` `execute` attribute, that way their corresponding properties will be updated on server side...

js

```
$("#someId").click();
```

---

On the other side , if you want to use managed bean data in servlets that corresponds to your jQuery calls you can always access that JSF managed data, like this : [JSF - get managed bean by name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2633733/617373)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i still think that even jQuery ajax and JSF ajax use different js library's a request can be made from one to the other becose i guess that both of them are actually dealing with HTTP request's so they can communicate..

Comment: well, now i surrender .. i was tying to detect on firebug how a commandLink with an <f:ajax> request URL is formed for i can do the same with jquery-ajax , i found this :

Comment: j_idt7=j_idt7&j_idt7%3Aj_idt11=mary&j_idt7%3Aj_idt13=mary&s_var1=&s_proclength=&s_taskId=&javax.faces.ViewState=-1257726806850207849%3A3895641171480667070&javax.faces.source=j_idt7%3Aj_idt50&javax.faces.partial.event=click&javax.faces.partial.execute=j_idt7%3Aj_idt50&javax.faces.partial.render=j_idt7%3Acontent&taskname=marytask&javax.faces.behavior.event=click&javax.faces.partial.ajax=true

Comment: : There re alot of jsf specific parameters sent, it s really hard to personalise this without to know all the theory behind it..

Comment: I don't think you should go there... anyway you should not use that hidden button too much... and when you do , its better than all the js code...

Answer (score 3):

In the same vein as pointed out by islandguy, if you use Primefaces, you woud use the `<p:remoteCommand/>` command, as follows :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      doAwesomeness();
</script>
```

with :

```
 <p:remoteCommand name="doAwesomeness" 
          actionListener="#{awesomeBean.awesomeMethod}"
          oncomplete="jsToExecuteOnAjaxSuccess()" />
```

Hope this helps..