# direct call of java bean values using ajax

Tags: java, ajax, javabeans

I want to call values from Java Managed beans using AJAX calls directly not using JSF capabilities. It means using simple AJAX or JQuery AJAX retrieve a value stored in a managed bean field, without using JSP write method; I have seen some samples doing this. and I think that's not a good solution. I should say as a test I want create a Web UI using plain HTML, CSS, JavaScript or AJAX and populate the UI with AJAX calls of any type without using any JSF UI components. Is it possible?

thanks,

Comment: Yes. It is certainly possible. There are several javascript libraries that will make your life much easier, such as: backbone, marionette, handlebars, _ (pronounced: underscore), require, etc.

Comment: which JSF framework are you using? JBoss rich faces does it by <a4j:jsFunction/>. Please have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475969/using-jquery-ajax-to-call-a-jsf-managed-bean-method-an-ajaxbehaviorevent-listen

Comment: @Shadow Creeper How can I do it without any frameworks? :)

Comment: @cpz I don't use any frameworks. I use pure JSF :) Is it possible to do it using the pure JSF itself?

Comment: @user805178 you either use existing frameworks or you write frameworks yourself... otherwise you end up with a mess that nobody wants to touch.

Comment: @user805178 if you just want to run a single ajax call, then you can easily do that using jQuery, the documentation is readily available. but for anything more complicated, i would highly suggest using some existing frameworks

Comment: @ShadowCreeper thanks, other than those libraries would you please give me some direct reference to documents?

Comment: @user805178 google is your friend... i'd start out looking at backbone.js, you can find examples on the web, and books too... try searching for "backbone tutorials"