# How to get JSF2.0 sessionMap reference from a servlet

Tags: servlets, jsf-2

Below code snippet is what I'm using.

```
ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
  Map<String, Object> sessionMap = externalContext.getSessionMap();
  sessionMap.put("User",user);
```

Now how can I get above "sessionMap" - "key" value from a plain "servlet"?
Will the code like this `(User)session.getAttribute("User");` work by any chance from my servlet?

Comment: use, request.getParameter("User");

Comment: If you see my JSF coding, I'm placing it in "session". Then how reading from "request" will work?

Comment: request.getSession().getAttribute("user");

Comment: How can you get FacesContext if your request didn't go through FacesServlet?

Comment: Nonetheless you will be able to get HttpSession object from your request, which holds all the attributes you put there before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSF - get managed bean by name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633112/jsf-get-managed-bean-by-name)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within a servlet the request / session / application attributes are availbale from within `doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)` / `doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)` methods:

```
//request attributes
String string = (String)request.getAttribute("username");
//session attributes
String string = (String)request.getSession().getAttribute("username");
//application attributes
String string = (String)getServletContext().getAttribute("beanName");
```

When the request was handled by the `FacesServlet`, the attributes are available as:

```
//request attributes
String string = (String)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().get("username");
//session attributes
String string = (String)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("username");
//application attributes
String string = (String)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getApplicationMap().get("username");
```

### Suggested reading

- [Communication in JSF 2.0 by BalusC: managed bean scopes](http://balusc.blogspot.ru/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ManagedBeanScopes);
- [JSF - get managed bean by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633112/jsf-get-managed-bean-by-name/2633733#2633733).