# JSF 2 ManagedProperty is null

Tags: jsf-2, nullpointerexception, managed-property

I know there are loads of questions on SO regarding this exact issue, but I couldn't find a solution to my problem. I'm trying to use a `@ManagedProperty` in JSF 2. I used the example from [this page](http://balusc.blogspot.com.es/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#InjectingManagedBeansInEachOther), but mine's not working:

```
@ManagedProperty("#{userSession}")
private UserSession userSession;
public void setUserSession(UserSession userSession) {
    this.userSession = userSession;
}
```

Both the parent bean and the bean injected are session scoped. Both beans have the `@ManagedBean` attribute. No faces-config.xml declarations, no EJBs, no use of Spring. One thing I noticed from that example is that both the bean classes implement `Serializable`. Mine do not, and I'm not sure if that is making the difference.

When I use this code, I get a `NullPointerException` when I try to operate on `userSession`. However, I know a session exists, because when I use @BalusC's [`findBean` convenience method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633112/jsf-get-managed-bean-by-name/), it works. One thing with this though, is that my code only works if I call `userSession = findBean("userSession")` inside the same method where I'm "doing stuff". If I initialize `userSession` in the bean's constructor, I get another NPE. Any ideas?

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to access it? In the constructor?

Comment: No getter for that bean. Also, is it throwing the NPE for the actual bean or a chained call to a member of the bean?

Comment: @BalusC I'm trying to access it in a private method, which is called in the constructor.

Comment: @kolossus A getter for which bean? You mean the ManagedProperty? Do I need a getter for the ManagedProperty if I only intend to access it from within the bean class? It is throwing a NPE when I try to do, e.g., `userSession.isAuthenticated()`. Also, after switching to using the `findBean` convenience method to init `userSession` immediately before use (and changing nothing else), the code worked as anticipated. So, doing it the `ManagedProperty` way (or the `findBean` way from inside the constructor is givng me `userSession == null`.

Comment: I've sometimes found when adding a new bean that I needed to restart the container for it to apply correctly. Doing a hot-redeploy of an application isn't always enough.