# Portlet IPC after received Event

Tags: jsf, events, event-handling, ipc, portlet

I have a Navigation portlet which schows all Students, when a Student gets clicked im sending a event with the id of the clicked student to other portlets. Sending and receiving the event is not the problem, that works fine. What I don't get, is how to proceed with the id of the Object.

How do I update the portlets receiving the event to show the data of the Object they received. Since i only get the id, the first stept is to search in the DB and get alle data, afterwards update the portlets view.

**Here my EventHandler:**

The hskaId is the id of the Object wchich i need.

```
    public class ReceivedFeedbackEventHandler implements BridgeEventHandler{

    @Override
    public EventNavigationResult handleEvent(FacesContext facesContext, Event event) {
         EventNavigationResult eventNavigationResult = null;
         String eventQName = event.getQName().toString();

         if (eventQName.equals("{http://liferay.com/events}ipc.studentSelected")) {
             System.out.print("EVENT RECIVED STUDENT");

             String hskaId = (String) event.getValue();

         }

         if(eventQName.equals("{http://liferay.com/events}ipc.projectSelected")) {
             System.out.print("EVENT RECIVED PROJECT");
         }

         return eventNavigationResult;
    }
}
```

In the ManagedBean of the Portlet, im calling this to get all Students of a hskaId. Where "hskaId" stands right now, should the recieved event value go.

```
Student student = StudentLocalServiceUtil.findByProjectId("hskaId");
```

How do i get the received value of the event to the ManagedBean and update the view?

This is a crosspost: [Link](https://www.liferay.com/de/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/54955644)

Comment: There's a (non-jsf) example contained in my "Ridiculously Simple Plugins" Webinar and in the accompanying [blog article and published code](https://www.liferay.com/de/web/olaf.kock/blog/-/blogs/ridiculously-simple-plugins-on-dev-li-1) that might help you find out how to update the view. The jsf part is up to you though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to programmatically get your `ManagedBean` via the `ELContext`.

Here's how you should do it:

```
String elExpression = "#{studentsModelBean}";
ELContext elContext = facesContext.getELContext();
ValueExpression valueExpression = facesContext.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createValueExpression(elContext, elExpression, StudentsModelBean.class);
StudentsModelBean studentsModelBean = (StudentsModelBean) valueExpression.getValue(elContext);
String hskaId = (String) event.getValue();
studentsModelBean.setStudent(hskaId);

String fromAction = null;
String outcome = "ipc.studentSelected";
eventNavigationResult = new EventNavigationResult(fromAction, outcome);
```

There is a working example of this which is done in the Liferay Faces [Customers and Bookings portlet demo](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-faces/blob/master/demos/bridge/jsf2-ipc-events-bookings-portlet/src/main/java/com/liferay/faces/demos/event/CustomerSelectedEventHandler.java#L54).

Comment: `Application#evaluateExpressionGet()` saves 3 lines. See also a.o. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2633733