# accessing a Java Bean from a different Java class

Tags: java, xpages, javabeans

I have a Java Bean called appProps defined as an ApplicationScope that is a Hashmap and of the type `<string, object>`. I can access it via SSJS using the format

```
var appDesc:String = appProps["some application name"].getAppDesc();
```

and this returns the application description which is stored in one of the fields in the Hashmap Object.

Now I need to call the same process in another JAVA Class.

The definition in the faces-config is:

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>appProps</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>ca.wfsystems.core.ApplicationMap</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>application</managed-bean-scope>
  </managed-bean>
```

Comment: This might help: [Get JSF managed bean by name in any Servlet related class][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633112/get-jsf-managed-bean-by-name-in-any-servlet-related-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best Java equivalent of the implicit lookup that SSJS and EL do for `appProps` there is:

```
ApplicationMap appProps = (ApplicationMap)ExtLibUtil.resolveVariable(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "appProps")
```

Comment: Because Jesse's too modest, he was the one who contributed the simplified method to ExtLib 14, which will allow you to avoid having to pass the FacesContext instance.

Comment: With a bit of search and figuring out which libraries to import this code works great. Thanks

Comment: Along those lines, you can generally hover your cursor over the class name or press ctrl-space at the end of the class name to have Designer try to find it for you.

Comment: Could you run into a scenario where the `resolveVariable` call throws an error because the bean hasn't been instantiated yet? I recall that I ran into that once (and solved it by instantiating and storing it myself).

Comment: resolveVariable should instantiate it if need be: it runs through the same routine as named access in SSJS. If you try to get the variable right from the scoped map, that's when it would be trouble.

Answer (score 0):

There are two easy solutions:

1. `ExtLibUtil.resolveVariable()` allows you to access it by the variable name declared in faces-config, so `appProps`. ExtLib 14 allows you to just pass the name.
2. Add a static `get()` method in the bean that uses `ExtLibUtil.resolveVariable()`. You can then call `ApplicationMap.get()`

Answer (score 0):

### Another (smart) way to access a java bean from a different java class

*This is your bean class:*

```
package ca.wfsystems.core;

import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

public class ApplicationMap {

    // Constants

    private static final String BEAN_NAME = "appProps"; //$NON-NLS-1$

    // Operations

    public static ApplicationMap getCurrentInstance() {
        // This is a neat way to get a handle on the instance of this bean in the scope from other Java code...
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); 
        return (ApplicationMap) context.getApplication().getVariableResolver().resolveVariable(context, BEAN_NAME);
    }

}
```

*And this one is a sample class using your bean class:*

```
package ca.wfsystems.core;

public class ApplicationMapClient {

    // Operations

    public void doSomeThing() {

        ApplicationMap appMap = ApplicationMap.getCurrentInstance();
        // Your code goes here....

    }

}
```

---

For further information take a look at the blog entry [a lesson on scoped managed beans in xpages](http://www.dalsgaard-data.eu/blog/a-lesson-on-scoped-managed-beans-in-xpages/) from John Dalsgaard.