# Backing beans (@ManagedBean) or CDI Beans (@Named)?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, cdi

I've just started reading through [Core JavaServer Faces, 3rd Ed.](http://horstmann.com/corejsf/) and they say this (emphasis mine):

> It is a historical accident that there are two separate mechanisms, CDI beans
>   and JSF managed beans, for beans that can be used in JSF pages. **We suggest
>   that you use CDI beans** unless your application must work on a plain servlet
>   runner such as Tomcat.

Why? They don't provide **any** justification. I've been using `@ManagedBean` for all the beans in a prototype application running on GlassFish 3, and I haven't really noticed any issues with this. I don't especially mind migrating from `@ManagedBean` to `@Named`, but I want to know **why I should bother**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are @ManagedBean's obsolete in JavaEE6 - because of @Named in CDI/Weld?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930889/are-managedbeans-obsolete-in-javaee6-because-of-named-in-cdi-weld)

Comment: @Bozho: that question is pretty similar, but after reading over Pascal's answer a few times, I still don't understand _why_ CDI is far superior. **I don't know CDI** and I'm happy to learn it since it is "better." Why is it better?

Comment: "unless your application must work on a plain servlet runner such as Tomcat"

I only use tomcat and I strongly recommend CDI. Tomcat can support it just fine

Comment: @KarlKildén "plain servlet runner" refers to a non-CDI capable servlet container.  At the time of writing Tomcat did not support CDI except with quite a bit of magic.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

CDI is preferred over plain JSF because CDI allows for JavaEE-wide dependency injection. You can also inject POJOs and let them be managed. With JSF you can only inject a subset of what you can with CDI.

Comment: So basically, I can inject an instance of almost any class (provided it has "the right stuff" - _what is it, just a no-arg constructor?_) with CDI, while I have to use `@ManagedBean` if I want to inject it with plain JSF?

Comment: @MattBall Matt after you years, can you comment on this migration?

Comment: @KorayTugay I haven't touched this code since June 2011 but I had switched to CDI and things worked just fine. I'm happy to answer any specific questions to the best of my memory if you've got them.

Answer (score 184):

## Use CDI.

As per JSF 2.3, `@ManagedBean` is **deprecated**. See also [spec issue 1417](https://github.com/javaee/javaserverfaces-spec/issues/1417). This means that there's not anymore a reason to choose `@ManagedBean` over `@Named`. This was first implemented in Mojarra 2.3.0 beta version m06.

[image]

Since Faces 4.0, the `@ManagedBean` has been **removed** as per spec [issue 1547](https://github.com/jakartaee/faces/issues/1547).

---

#### History

The core difference is, [`@ManagedBean`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/faces/bean/managedbean) is managed by JSF framework and is only via [`@ManagedProperty`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/faces/bean/managedproperty) available to another JSF managed beans. [`@Named`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/inject/named) is managed by application server (the container) via CDI framework and is via [`@Inject`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/inject/inject) available to any kind of a container managed artifact like `@WebListener`, `@WebFilter`, `@WebServlet`, `@Path`, `@Stateless`, etc and even a JSF `@ManagedBean`. From the other side on, `@ManagedProperty` does **not** work inside a `@Named` or any other container managed artifact. It works really only inside `@ManagedBean`.

Another difference is that CDI actually injects proxies delegating to the current instance in the target scope on a per-request/thread basis (like as how EJBs are been injected). This mechanism allows injecting a bean of a narrower scope in a bean of a broader scope, which isn't possible with JSF `@ManagedProperty`. JSF "injects" here the physical instance directly by invoking a setter (that's also exactly why a setter is required, while that is **not** required with `@Inject`).

While not directly a disadvantage — there are other ways — the scope of `@ManagedBean` is simply limited. From the other perspective, if you don't want to expose "too much" for `@Inject`, you can also just keep your managed beans `@ManagedBean`. It's like `protected` versus `public`. But that doesn't really count.

At least, in JSF 2.0/2.1, the major disadvantage of managing JSF backing beans by CDI is that there's no CDI equivalent of `@ViewScoped`. The `@ConversationScoped` comes close, but still requires manually starting and stopping and it appends an ugly `cid` request parameter to outcome URLs. MyFaces CODI makes it easier by fully transparently bridging JSF's `javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped` to CDI so you can just do `@Named @ViewScoped`, however that appends an ugly `windowId` request parameter to outcome URLs, also on plain vanilla page-to-page navigation. [OmniFaces](https://omnifaces.org) solves this all with a true CDI [`@ViewScoped`](https://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/ViewScoped) which really ties the bean's scope to JSF view state instead of to an arbitrary request parameter.

JSF 2.2 (which is released 3 years after this question/answer) offers a new fully CDI compatible `@ViewScoped` annotation out the box in flavor of `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped`. JSF 2.2 even comes along with a CDI-only `@FlowScoped` which doesn't have a `@ManagedBean` equivalent, hereby pushing JSF users towards CDI. The expectation is that `@ManagedBean` and friends will be deprecated as per Java EE 8. If you're currently still using `@ManagedBean`, it's therefore strongly recommend to switch to CDI to be prepared for future upgrade paths. CDI is readily available in Java EE Web Profile compatible containers, such as WildFly, TomEE and GlassFish. For Tomcat, you have to install it separately, exactly as you already did for JSF. See also [How to install CDI in Tomcat?](https://balusc.omnifaces.org/2013/10/how-to-install-cdi-in-tomcat.html)

Comment: I've created `beans.xml`, converted `@ManagedBean` backing beans to `@Named`, and converted `@ManagedProperty` to `@Inject`. All is well with the world. However, if I change my `@EJB` annotations to `@Inject`, deployment fails (`org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException`) with message `WELD-001408 Injection point has unsatisfied dependencies`. Should I actually be using `@Inject` to inject no-interface EJBs into an `@Named` bean, or should I stick with `@EJB`? The EJBs are packaged in an EJB JAR, in the same EAR as the WAR that contains my CDI beans.

Comment: It should just work. Are you still facing this problem with the current Weld version?

Comment: Alas, I couldn't say. This question is from 2 employers and >2 years ago. Based on my old comment on Bozho's answer, I must have switched over to CDI/`@Named`.

Comment: _"MyFaces CODI makes it easier by fully transparently bridging JSF's javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped to CDI so you can just do `@Named @ViewScoped`, however that appends an ugly windowId request parameter to outcome URLs, also on plain vanilla page-to-page navigation."_  
Note that with DeltaSpike this no longer holds true. You can disable both the dsId and windowId URL parameters, if you don't need the Window Scope.

Comment: @Jan: And in the meanwhile, OmniFaces has also a JSF 2.2-like `@ViewScoped` for JSF 2.0/2.1: http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/ViewScoped

Answer (score 17):

With Java EE 6 and CDI you have different option for Managed Beans

- `@javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean` is refer to JSR 314 and was introduced with JSF 2.0. The main goal was to avoid the configuration in the faces-config.xml file to use the bean inside an JSF Page.
- `@javax.annotation.ManagedBean(“myBean”)` is defined by JSR 316. It generalizes the JSF managed beans for use elsewhere in Java EE
- `@javax.inject.Named(“myBean”)` are almost the same, as that one above, except you need a beans.xml file in the web/WEB-INF Folder to activate CDI.

Comment: What is the difference between the first two?

Comment: The goal of the first annotation is/was to replace the bean configuration in the faces-config.xml for the usage in JSF. The second one copy the concept into the "java ee 6 container". It has more functions (like @PostConstruct and @PreDestroy annotations), but is also reachable by the JSF Page (with Expression Language).

Comment: why do you need a `beans.xml` file?  Is this still true today?

Comment: No, with JavaEE7 you don't need the beans.xml any more. see https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/cdi-adv001.htm

Comment: With JavaEE7 you don't need the beans.xml:  
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/cdi-adv001.htm (correct link)  
https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/default_cdi_enablement_in_java (Default CDI Enablement in Java EE 7)

Answer (score 2):

I was using CDI in GlassFish 3.0.1, but to get it to work I had to import the Seam 3 framework (Weld).  That worked pretty well.

In GlassFish 3.1 CDI stopped working, and the Seam Weld stopped working with it.  I opened a [bug on this](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-14841) but haven't seen it fixed yet.  I had to convert all my code to using the javax.faces.* annotations but I plan to move back to CDI once they get it working.

I agree you should use CDI, but one issue that I haven't seen resolved yet is what to do with the @ViewScoped annotation.  I have a lot of code that depends on it.   It is not clear whether @ViewScoped works if you are not using @ManagedBean with it.  If anyone can clarify this I would appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

One good reason to move to CDI: you could have a common session-scoped resource (user profile for example) `@Inject`'ed into both JSF managed beans and REST services (i.e., Jersey/JAX-RS).

On the other hand, `@ViewScoped` is a compelling reason to stick with JSF `@ManagedBean` - especially for anything with significant AJAX. There is no standard replacement for this in CDI.

Seems that it may have some support for a `@ViewScoped`-like annotation for CDI beans, but I haven't played with it personally.

http://seamframework.org/Seam3/FacesModule