# How to keep a bean alive for the through session accessible from filter and EJB

Tags: java, cdi, javabeans, session-bean

I am trying to set a property to a bean `ModelBean` in a Filter and access this property in a JSF controller `IndexController`.

The ModelBean is annotated `@SessionScoped` and it is used in the filter and controller with `@Inject`. The problem is that two separate instances are created and I cannot access the property that I set in filter.

What would be the best way to keep the bean alive throughout the session? Or maybe there is a better method to pass data from the filter?

```
@SessionScoped
public class ModelBean{
    private String deviceId;

    public ModelBean() {
        super();
    }

    public String getDeviceId() {
        return deviceId;
    }

    public void setDeviceId(String deviceId) {
        this.deviceId = deviceId;
    }
}
```

```
@Provider
public class AuthRequestFilter implements Filter {

    @Inject
    ModelBean model;


    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws
            IOException, ServletException {

        // the device id is set just fine
        model.setDeviceId(deviceId);
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        return;
    }
}
```

```
@Named(value = "indexController")
public class IndexController {

    @Inject
    ModelBean model;

    // the method **is* called from the xhtml
    public String justAnExample() {
        // this is the problem, the deviceId is null=>
        return model.getDeviceId();
    }
}
```

Comment: If two instances are created most likely **you**  made and error. But simce there is no [mcve], it is **impossible** to help

Comment: @Kukeltje thanks for the recommendation. I have Added the code, hope this makes the question more understandable. Let me know if there is anything else that seems unclear to you.

Comment: How do ypu determine you have two different imstances? And what is the package of `@SessionScoped`? And wjatbis ypur JSF bersion and implementation?

Comment: @Kukeltje the package is `javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped`. And I determine that those are different objects when I see they have different ids in debug.

Comment: sorry for the typo's btw... quick typing on my phone ;-)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470440/sessionscoped-bean-looses-scope-and-gets-recreated-all-the-time-fields-become.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Kukeltje for the suggestion to look into the packages. I still Don't know why the package `javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped` that I was using did not keep the bean alive, but replacing it with `javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped` did the trick. The bean is now alive and the data can be passed.

Comment: No need to answer... There is a duplicate for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470440/sessionscoped-bean-looses-scope-and-gets-recreated-all-the-time-fields-become, but in your case it is the 'reverse'