# Input given in JSF page does not set that value to managed bean variable

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

Am a newbie to JSF. Am using JSF 2 and primefaces 4.0 in my application. As stated in the Title, the input value given in the xhtml page, does not set the value to the ManagedBean. I have tried all the possible combination.

**growlMessage.xhtml**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>

    </h:head>

   <h:body>
    <h:form> 
  <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="true" />  

    <p:panel id="panelID" header="Growl">  
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">  
            <h:outputLabel for="msg" value="Message:" />   
            <p:inputText id="msg" value="#{growlView.message}" required="true" />  
        </h:panelGrid>  
      <p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{growlView.saveMessage}"/>  
    </p:panel> 

   </h:form>  
    </h:body>
</html>
```

`
**GrowlView.java:**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;


@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class GrowlView implements Serializable{

    private String message;

    public GrowlView() {
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }


    public void saveMessage(){
        System.out.println("@@@@@  hello");
        System.out.println("@@@@@"+ getMessage());
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Successful", "Your message: "+message));
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Second message", "Additional Message details"));
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a good reason to use JSF 2.0 instead of 2.2? You should use CDI instead of JSF managed beans, which is more or less deprecated. So, use

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class GrowlView implements Serializable
```

Be sure the ViewScoped annotation is from javax.faces.view. And the beginning of the xhtml should use the new namespace:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
```

Comment: Why should he do that? JSF 2.0 works fine. You don't always have to add such huge things like CDI to your project if it isn't crucial.

Comment: Because I tested his code and only got it working when doing this. Oh, and because it is recommended to move towards CDI: https://weblogs.java.net/blog/mriem/archive/2013/10/30/jsf-tip-30-migrate-your-managedbean-named-annotations and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347374/backing-beans-managedbean-or-cdi-beans-named. For at beginner it gives no meaning AT ALL to start out with JSF managed beans, unless you know you are going to maintain an existing system. But thank you very much for the downvote.

Comment: In this easy example CDI won't be necessary.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's effort. I found the solution and my application is running correctly

Answer (score 0):

Your commandButton should look like this (according to PrimeFaces showcase):

```
<p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{growlView.saveMessage}" update="growl"/>
```

Have you tried setting a larger scope to your managed bean, for example `@SessionScoped` ?
(just for testing purposes). So you could exclude a possible scope problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this following code: using the `process` and `partialSubmit` attributes:

```
<p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{growlView.saveMessage}" update="growl" process="@form" partialSubmit="true"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

hy,

change for

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>

    </h:head>

   <h:body>
    <h:form> 
  <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="true" autoUpdate="true"/>  

    <p:panel id="panelID" header="Growl">  
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">  
            <h:outputLabel for="msg" value="Message:" />   
            <p:inputText id="msg" value="#{pageView.message}" required="true" />  
        </h:panelGrid>  
      <p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{pageView.saveMessage}" update="growl"/>  
    </p:panel> 

   </h:form>  
    </h:body>
</html>
```

and replace

```
@ManagedBean
```

with

```
@ManagedBean(name="pageView")
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. unfortunately this solution does not work.Managed bean doesn't get fired.

Comment: give me what you have see in the console

Comment: I dint get any Result. when I press save button, it has to show the message which I gave as input. but it doesn't do anything. It seems the bean doesn't get fired

Comment: you see in the console this: @@@@@  hello ?

Comment: No . The content given in the S.O.P statement is not getting printed. saveMessage() method doesnot get invoked

Comment: ok, i have update my responce try it

Comment: No. Still it doesn't work

Comment: verify your console javascript if she is error, i would more information for help you, you have error in console eclipse or netbeans or in your page, what you read in console?. you can replace '@ViewScoped' with  '@SessionScoped' and try

Comment: Sorry None of the solution works. I have changed the scope and tried. neither error nor warning is thrown. Thanks for spending your valuable time.

Comment: i think you have another problem not code, if you like send me your project in my email and a see it,