# Inject a singleton bean into a request scoped JAX-RS resource

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, singleton, jax-rs, cdi

I am trying to inject a Singleton bean into my Request scoped JAX-RS resource. What I notice is that my Singleton's constructor is invoked on every request, which is obviously not the desired behavior. My Code artifacts are as below:-

JAX-RS Resource

```
@Path("/thing")
@ManagedBean
public class ThingResource {

    //This is desired to be Singleton
    @Inject
    @RedisThingDb
    private ThingDb thingDb;

    //This is request scoped
    @Inject
    private MyRequestScopedObj obj;

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Thing getById(@PathParam("id") String thingId) {
        return thingDb.findById(thingId);
    }
}
```

@RedisThingDb Annotation that marks it as a Singleton

```
@Qualifier
@Singleton
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER     })
public @interface RedisThingDb {

}
```

Producer Code that creates the RedisDb object.

```
@Produces
@RedisThingDb
public ThingDb getRedisDb() {
    return new RedisDb();// This should be called once, because @RedisThingDb is singleton.
}
```

RedisDb

```
public class RedisDb implements ThingDb {
    public RedisDb() {
    logger.debug("Constructing...");
    }

    public Thing findById(Long id){
     ...
    }
}
```

Dependency from pom.xml (Implementation is Wildfly container)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I am using javax.annotation.ManagedBean (@ManagedBean) annotation to turn the JAX-RS into a CDI managed bean. The @RedisThingDb annotation is marked as @Singleton. The JAX-RS resource is request scoped and has other request scoped beans injected into it.

Comment: Can you specify what version of JAX-RS/Java EE you're using?

Comment: @JohnAment my maven dependency is as follows:-  

    <dependency>  
      <groupId>javax</groupId>  
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>7.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

I am running on WildFly

Comment: @JohnAment sorry could not figure out how to format my comment correctly. I am using javax.javaee-api 7.0 scope is provided and on Wildfly application container

Comment: Great thanks.  would you also be able to post your `beans.xml` in the question as well?

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues I see with your code.  For one, you're using `@RedisThingDB` as a `@Stereotype` but it's not annotated `@Stereotype`.  You should ditch the `@Qualifier` on it as well.

Second, which is more of a recommendation, is that you should annotate your endpoint with a scope.  RESTEasy will add a scope for you, `@RequestScoped`.

Third, it's completely ok for the constructor to be called multiple times.  The real thing to watch is if your `@PostConstruct` method is repeatedly invoked.  The constructor gets invoked since CDI uses proxies.  If that still doesn't help - try using `@ApplicationScoped` rather than `@Singleton`.

Answer (score -1):

@ManagedBean is from JSF and not related to CDI
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedBean.html

replace it with @Named

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Named.html

Comment: Don't use `@Named` on non GUI objects.

Comment: Why? '@Named' is for general usage, same as '@Component' in Spring, for example.

Comment: There is a javax.annotation.ManagedBean as well.

Comment: Which works right like JSF ManagedBean) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347374/backing-beans-managedbean-or-cdi-beans-named/4397444#4397444

Comment: Scopes are considered more "bean defining" that anything in CDI.  Most JAX-RS runtimes will support injection when they see `@RequestScoped` or `@ApplicationScoped` on the resource class.