# JSF @managedproperty and @PostConstruct

Tags: jsf, netbeans, postconstruct, managed-property

I have a problem with JSF2 @ManagedProperty annotation. I have a managed bean that create a user, then i want to pass this user to another bean to display other informations relative to that user. So my code is below :

```
@Named("userController")
@SessionScoped
public class UserController implements Serializable {

@EJB
private session.UserFacade ejbFacade;
private List<User> items = null;
private User selected;
private User utente;
private String user;
private String pass;
----getter and setter----
```

In the Schedule Bean I use the userController bean in the @PostConstruct :

```
@Named(value = "scheduleController")
@SessionScoped
public class ScheduleController implements Serializable {

private ScheduleModel eventModel;  

private ScheduleEvent event = new DefaultScheduleEvent();

@EJB
ActivityFacade ejbFacade;

@ManagedProperty(value="#{userController}")
private UserController credentials;


public ScheduleController() {        
}

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    eventModel = new DefaultScheduleModel();       
    List<Activity> daFare =ejbFacade.findForUser(credentials.getUtente().getIdUser());
    for(int i=0;i<daFare.size();i++){
        eventModel.addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent(daFare.get(i).getDescrizione(),daFare.get(i).getDalleOre(),daFare.get(i).getAlleOre() ));
    }
}

public void setCredentials(UserController credentials) {
    this.credentials = credentials;
}
```

When i debug the code, I see that the UserController credentials is always null.... What's wrong ? I need to specify something in faces-config.xml ?
Thanks a lot for your tips.

**EDIT :**

After change @ManagedProperty with @Inject and after add the below beans.xml in WEB-INF folder, the problem persist.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
```

The app work in this way: 
A user can log in via this xhtml page:

```
<body>
    <h:form>  
        <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />
        <p:panel header="Inserisci i tuoi dati" style="margin: 0 auto; text-align: center" >
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5" style="margin: 0 auto; text-align: center">
                <p:outputLabel value="Username"/>
                <p:inputText value="#{userController.user}"  required="true" label="Username"   size="40"/>
                <p:outputLabel value="Password" />
                <p:password  value="#{userController.pass}"  required="true" label="Password" size="40"/>
                <p:commandButton action="#{userController.validateLogin}" value="Login"  update="msgs" ajax="false" style="text-align: center"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>         
    </h:form>

</body>
```

After submit the form, the userController verify that this specific user exist in a DB table and then instantiate the User utente ( id, username, password, email as field ). After this, the app redirect to home.xhtml that display several user's information and select several information of a DB table selected by user's id.
Here is the code where I set User utente:

```
public String validateLogin(){

    String output="home";
    boolean exist=false;
    exist=ejbFacade.logValid(user,pass);
    if(!exist){
        //FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,"Username o Password errata","Contattare l'amministratore"));             
        return "index";
    }else{
        utente=ejbFacade.setUtente(user);  
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();          
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Accesso eseguito con successo.","Bentornato " + user));
        return output;
    }
}
```

The code sequence in which i control the existece of a user and set the utente is:

```
@Stateless
public class UserFacade extends AbstractFacade<User> {
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "ImmobiliareWebPU")
private EntityManager em;

@Override
protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
}

public UserFacade() {
    super(User.class);
}

public boolean logValid(String user, String pass) {
    List<User> utente ;
    boolean autorizzato;
    String find = "User.findByUsername&Password";
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery(find, User.class);
    query.setParameter("username", user);
    query.setParameter("password", pass);
    utente =query.getResultList();
    if (utente.isEmpty()) {
        autorizzato=false;           
    }
    else{
       autorizzato=true;                      
    }
    return autorizzato;
}

public User setUtente(String user) {
    //SETTO L'UTENTE PER LA SESSIONE DEL PROGRAMMA
    User utente;
    String find = "User.findByUsername";
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery(find, User.class);
    query.setParameter("username", user);       
    utente =(User) query.getSingleResult();

    return utente;
}
```

}

the code where I need user's information is :

```
@Named(value = "scheduleController")
@RequestScoped
public class ScheduleController implements Serializable {

private ScheduleModel eventModel;  

private ScheduleEvent event = new DefaultScheduleEvent();

@EJB
ActivityFacade ejbFacade;

@Inject
private UserController credentials;


public ScheduleController() {        
}

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    eventModel = new DefaultScheduleModel();       
    List<Activity> daFare =ejbFacade.findForUser(credentials.getUtente().getIdUser());
    for(int i=0;i<daFare.size();i++){
        eventModel.addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent(daFare.get(i).getDescrizione(),daFare.get(i).getDalleOre(),daFare.get(i).getAlleOre() ));
    }
}
```

In the ejbFacade i make a simple query :

```
@Stateless
public class ActivityFacade extends AbstractFacade<Activity> {
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "ImmobiliareWebPU")
private EntityManager em;

@Override
protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
}

public ActivityFacade() {
    super(Activity.class);
}

public List<Activity> findForUser(int utenteId) {
    //RICHIEDO LE ATTIVITA' DEL SINGOLO UTENTE
    List<Activity> daFare ;
    String find = "Activity.findByUserId";
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery(find, Activity.class);
    query.setParameter("idUser", utenteId);
    daFare =query.getResultList();

    return daFare;
}

}
```

In debug mode i see an istance of UserController with all null fields; it seems to be a new istance of UserController. I use also "import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped" . Where is my fault ?

Comment: If you debug `utente = ejbFacade.setUtente(user);` line, is `utente` not null? I'd say the method `setUtente(...)` either is wrong named (you are trying to ***get*** an entity from EJB) or is not the appropriate method given your code.

Comment: utente is not null. It has all the right field value. Which is the right way to an entity from a DB table ? I though that get it from EJB facade was the best way.... I added the code sequence above @dic19

Comment: The way is right, but I'd rename `setUtente(...)` to `getUtentePerNome(...)` since that's what the method actually does. Everything in your code looks fine and should work ok, I don't see nothing strange. Note there's a missing `</beans>` tag in your `beans.xml` but I think it's just a copy-paste issue.

Comment: I rename the method as you suggest. But the app doesn't work. Is there something that i have to configure in glassfish or in Netbeans ? Where I've to put the beans.xml file ? I've put it in WEB-INF folder, is it right ? Is the PostConstruct be a problem ?

Comment: Please my beans.xml example. You can auto-generate this file in NetBeans.

Comment: Done and it doesn't work. Always the same....

Comment: Obviously I test another basic app that work in the same way and all works fine. This is an informatic mistery !!!!

Comment: Yes, this things just happen... As I've said it all looks good to me. Hope you can solve it! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When i debug the code, I see that the UserController credentials is
>   always null.... What's wrong?

Please note you are mixing up [CDI (Context and Dependency Injection)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/partcdi.htm) with Managed properties, which is probably causing the described behavior. Your beans are annotated with `@Named` instead of `@ManagedBean` so this:

```
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{userController}")
    private UserController credentials;
```

Should be replaced by this:

```
    @Inject
    private UserController credentials;
```

For a really great explanation about the difference between CDI and backing beans see @BalusC answer in this topic: [Backing beans (@ManagedBean) or CDI Beans (@Named)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347374/backing-beans-managedbean-or-cdi-beans-named).

---

> I need to specify something in faces-config.xml?

No, but you should include a `beans.xml` like exemplified here: [Packaging CDI applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/cdi-adv001.htm). As far as I remember this file is mandatory regardless the discovery mode. Here is the `beans.xml` that you can auto-generate in NetBeans:

*New file* --> *Context and Dependency Injection* --> *beans.xml (CDI Configuration file)*.

This is all I've ever needed to make CDI work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="annotated">
</beans>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I know that there is a difference between Named and ManagedBean. But the problem persist ! Now, after replace ManagedProperties with Inject, and create a blank beans.xml file, when debug the code, i see the variables that contains the injected UserController has all null fields. There something i should change ? It seems to be a new istance of UserController, not the first that I istanciated. Thanks again for your replies.

Comment: Well the good news is injection is working. Note that you don't have to explicitely instatiate nothing because both beans are managed. If `UserController` looks like a new instance is because the container didn't create an instance before (because it wasn't needed). It's hard to give you a specific answer withouth knowing the flow in your application. Maybe you can post the sequence in what your beans are being called, not just their definition. @ClaudioCerino

Comment: I have edit the question with the code sequence. I hope you can illuminate me. Thanks again @dic19