# @Named bean "hello world" with @ApplicationScoped (CDI) on Glassfish

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi, el

How do I get output from the `NextClient` bean, which uses CDI, to the facelet?

I'm trying to use CDI imports:

```
package dur.beans;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;


@Named("nextClient")
@ApplicationScoped
public class NextClient implements NextClientLocal {

    private int next = 1009;

    @Override
    public int getNext() {
        next = next + 1;
        return next;
    }

}
```

with a facelets example:

```
<!DOCTYPE    html  PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0  Transitional//EN"  
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      >

    <h:head></h:head>
    <h:body>
        This and everything before will be ignored
        <ui:composition template="template.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="navigation">
                <ui:include src="menu.xhtml"/>
            </ui:define>
            <ui:define name="main">
                <h1>bird</h1>
                <p>
                    next   #{nextClient.next}
                </p>
            </ui:define>
        </ui:composition>
        This and everything after will be ignored
    </h:body>
</html>
```

and yet there doesn't seem to be any output from the bean:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ lynx -dump http://localhost:8080/EntAppWeb-war/next.xhtml                                    birds...

crud ops
     __________________________________________________________________

   [1]Home
   [2]Parrot
   [3]Eagle
   [4]Falcon
   [5]next

                                      bird

   next

References

   1. http://localhost:8080/EntAppWeb-war/next.xhtml
   2. http://localhost:8080/EntAppWeb-war/next.xhtml
   3. http://localhost:8080/EntAppWeb-war/next.xhtml
   4. http://localhost:8080/EntAppWeb-war/next.xhtml
   5. http://localhost:8080/EntAppWeb-war/next.xhtml
thufir@dur:~$
```

This example is adapted from [Facelets Essentials](http://www.apress.com/9781430210498); I'd like to use CDI, however.

is the problem with `beans.xml`?  Some places say it's optional, others that `beans.xml` is required.  It seems optional:

> 23.13 Configuring a CDI Application
>
> When your beans are annotated with a scope type, the server recognizes
>   the application as a bean archive and no additional configuration is
>   required. The possible scope types for CDI beans are listed in Using
>   Scopes. CDI uses an optional deployment descriptor named beans.xml.
>   Like other Java EE deployment descriptors, the configuration settings
>   in beans.xml are used in addition to annotation settings in CDI
>   classes. The settings in beans.xml override the annotation settings if
>   there is a conflict. An archive must contain the beans.xml deployment
>   descriptor only in certain limited situations...

The Java EE 7
Tutorial
Release 7 for Java EE Platform
p 404

From what I've read, it seems that CDI is recommended over `@ManagedBean`, for example.  I've not found a simpler example, than this, to start from.

see also:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4397444/262852

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26110888/what-is-the-alternative-to-managedbean

source code:

https://github.com/THUFIR/EntAppWeb

Comment: It didn't work for me (my example, same as yours) until I went to  .../next.jsf (note the .jsf)

Answer (score 1):

The backing bean is correct. You need to check that your server supports CDI or you would need to use some extra libraries to make it work (e.g. Apache Tomcat).

I think the beans.xml with CDI is required as the container needs to scan all the beans that are annotated with CDI annotations.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="annotated">
</beans>
```

This **bean-discovery-mode="annotated"** is what scan your classes.

Comment: I created branch 4 as: https://github.com/THUFIR/EntAppWeb/tree/4_increments_correctly with working bean/xhtml, doesn't need `beans.xml`.  I don't know why it wasn't working before.  Maybe I made an error in deploying it; but I was careful to recreate the .ear and undeploy, then deploy to glassfish.  I don't mind that it works now, but I don't understand why it wasn't.  Maybe my deployment error...