# Can't Access session scoped JSF managed bean in web filter

Tags: jsf, servlet-filters, jsf-2.2

I have a JSF 2.2 application  with login page I need to control users access to the pages so I wrote a web filter but the problem is that it always return null when I try to access the session scoped JSF managed bean. I already logged in and I made sure that the login works fine  and the user set correctly but still when I access the bean it returns null

here is my filter code to access the bean

```
UserLogin loginBean = (UserLogin) ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession().getAttribute("userLogin");
```

here is the bean code with the login in method

```
@Named(value = "userLogin") @SessionScoped @ManagedBean
public class UserLogin implements Serializable {

  /**
   * Creates a new instance of UserLogin
   */
  public UserLogin() {}
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1520318172495977648L;
  private User user = null;

  String email, password;

  public String getEmail() {
    return email;
  }

  public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
  }



  public String getPassword() {
    return password;
  }

  public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
  }

  public User getUser() {
    return user;
  }

  public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
  }



  public void login() {
    UserHelper userHelper = new UserHelper();
    user = userHelper.Login(email, password);
    if (user != null) {
      FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Successful", "Welcomesss :" + user.getFirstname());
      FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    } else {
      FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Failed", "Wrong Usernames or password.");
      msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
      FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }

  }

}
```

I wrote a sample code to retrive all the session attrbuties but I couldn't find userLogin 
here is the method along with its output

```
 Enumeration attrs = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession().getAttributeNames();
 while (attrs.hasMoreElements()) {

   LOG.log(Logger.Level.FATAL, attrs.nextElement());
 }






FATAL: WELD_S #10
FATAL:   com.sun.faces.application.view.activeViewMaps
FATAL:   org.jboss.weld.context.conversation.ConversationIdGenerator
FATAL:   com.sun.faces.renderkit.ServerSideStateHelper.LogicalViewMap
FATAL:   org.jboss.weld.context.ConversationContext.conversations
FATAL:   com.sun.faces.application.view.activeViewContexts
FATAL:   javax.faces.request.charset
FATAL:   org.jboss.weld.context.beanstore.http.LockStore
```

Comment: What is the import of your `@SessionScoped` ?

Comment: I want to get the values of this bean later from the session in the filter.

Comment: @Ahemd Saad I understand, but I asked about the import statement of SessionScoped, "import ... " ?

Comment: import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using both `@ManagedBean` and `@Named` annotations, you must use only one of them.

As you are using `javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped` for the `@SessionScoped` which mean that you are using [CDI Managed beans](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjfzi.html), then you should only use `@Named` to make your bean CDI managed.

You can check [BalusC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4347707/4170582) for more informations about the difference between `@Named` and `@ManagedBean` annotations

### Update:

Regarding your comment, you don't need to use the:

```
UserLogin loginBean = (UserLogin) ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession().getAttribute("userLogin")
```

You can just use it like this:

```
public class YourFilter { 

@Inject
UserLogin loginBean;

...

}
```

Comment: Hello Tarik,
I have updated my bean to be 
@Named(value = "loginbean")
@SessionScoped
public class UserLogin implements Serializable {...}

and now  in my  filter I am using the following line to get the value

UserLogin loginBean = (UserLogin)  httpServletRequest.getSession().getAttribute("loginbean");

Comment: why you want to use that line to get the value?  if you want to use it in another Bean you can just use @Inject

Comment: I am using this line in the filter   I am using filter to check if the user authenticated or no.

Comment: @AhmedSaad I added an example to my answer

Comment: Man you are just awesome !!   just please update your solution and remove the request scope.... now it works perfect ! Thx a ton