# Showing a result from DB table as a List in Java Web App

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jsf

I'm using Spring, Hibernate and JSF for a web application.
In my case I have a Table User having many columns, one of those is idRole. idRole is a foreign key from table Role which containes Id of the role and the role name.
What I want to know is how to make the role name shown in my place of the ID, and make that field a List showing only possible roles (which are all the columns of the Roles table)

Here is my ManagedBean :

```
package managedController;

import org.primefaces.event.RowEditEvent;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import spring.model.Customer;
import spring.service.CustomerService;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@ManagedBean(name="customerMB")
@RequestScoped
public class CustomerManagedBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final String SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String ERROR   = "error";

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{CustomerService}")
    CustomerService customerService;

    List<Customer> customerList;

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    public String addCustomer() {
        try {
            Customer customer = new Customer();
            customer.setId(getId());
            customer.setName(getName());
            customer.setSurname(getSurname());
            getCustomerService().addCustomer(customer);
            reset();
            return SUCCESS;
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ERROR;
    }

    public String updateCustomer(Customer customer) {
        try {
            getCustomerService().updateCustomer(customer);
            return SUCCESS;
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ERROR;
    }

    public String deleteCustomer(Customer customer) {
        try {
            getCustomerService().deleteCustomer(customer);
            customerList = null;
            getCustomerList();
            return SUCCESS;
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ERROR;
    }

    public void onEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Item Edited");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        updateCustomer((Customer)event.getObject());
    }

    public void onCancel(RowEditEvent event) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Item Cancelled");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }

    public void reset() {
        this.setId(0);
        this.setName("");
        this.setSurname("");
    }

    public List<Customer> getCustomerList() {
        if(customerList == null){
            customerList = new ArrayList<Customer>();
            customerList.addAll(getCustomerService().getCustomers());
        }
        return customerList;
    }

    public CustomerService getCustomerService() {
        return customerService;
    }

    public void setCustomerService(CustomerService customerService) {
        this.customerService = customerService;
    }

    public void setCustomerList(List<Customer> customerList) {
        this.customerList = customerList;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

}
```

and here is the file where I show them (Users or Customers let's say) :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags">

<h:head>
    <title>Welcome</title>

</h:head>

<h:body>

    <!-- View element level Spring Security : only can view for who has the role 'ROLE_ADMIN' -->
    <sec:authorize access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
        <h:form id="form2">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><h:outputLabel for="id" value="Id : "/></td>
                    <td><p:inputText id="id" value="#{customerMB.id}">
                        <f:converter converterId="javax.faces.Integer"/>
                        <p:ajax event="blur" update="idMsg"/>
                    </p:inputText>
                        <p:message id="idMsg" for="id" display="icon"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><h:outputLabel for="name" value="Name : "/></td>
                    <td><p:inputText id="name" value="#{customerMB.name}">
                        <f:validateLength minimum="1"/>
                        <p:ajax event="blur" update="nameMsg"/>
                    </p:inputText>
                        <p:message id="nameMsg" for="name" display="icon"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><h:outputLabel for="surname" value="Surname : "/></td>
                    <td><p:inputText id="surname" value="#{customerMB.surname}">
                        <f:validateLength minimum="1"/>
                        <p:ajax event="blur" update="surnameMsg"/>
                    </p:inputText>
                        <p:message id="surnameMsg" for="surname" display="icon"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><p:commandButton id="addUser" value="Add" action="#{customerMB.addCustomer}" ajax="false"/></td>
                    <td><p:commandButton id="reset" value="Reset" action="#{customerMB.reset}" ajax="false"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </h:form>
    </sec:authorize>

    <br/>

    <h:form id="form1">
        <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>
        <p:dataTable id="customers" var="customer" value="#{customerMB.customerList}" style="width: 10%" editable="true">
            <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{customerMB.onEdit}" update=":form1:messages"/>
            <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{customerMB.onCancel}" update=":form1:messages"/>
            <p:column headerText="ID">
                <h:outputText value="#{customer.id}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Name">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Name"/>
                </f:facet>
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{customer.name}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{customer.name}" label="name"/>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Surname">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{customer.surname}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{customer.surname}" label="surname"/>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>
            <sec:authorize access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Delete</f:facet>
                    <h:commandLink value="Delete" action="#{customerMB.deleteCustomer(customer)}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column style="width:20%">
                    <f:facet name="header">Update</f:facet>
                    <p:rowEditor/>
                </p:column>
            </sec:authorize>
        </p:dataTable>
        <br/>
        <p:commandButton value="Logout" id="logout" action="#{loginBean.logout}"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>

</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: Where are your entities ? There is no user and no role just consumers in a list in your code. So you want a selectOneMenu with all the roles possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ManagedBean(name="customerMB")
@RequestScoped
...
@ManagedProperty(value="#{CustomerService}")
CustomerService customerService;
```

It's [advised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347374/backing-beans-managedbean-or-cdi-beans-named) to switch those to :

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
...
@Inject or @EJB
SomeService ss;
//for a managed property just use Inject without parameters.
```

Your code will still work. But take the `javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped` package for request scoped.

Since you didn't post any entity whatsoever and probably copy pasted the tutorial, I'll post smtg generic to give you a general idea of how to go with it:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class Mybean {

   private List<User> userLists; // +getters and setters
   @EJB
   private SomeService ss;

   //make the call to the Db in a PostConstruct annotated method, NOT in the constructor. So the injections are done.
   @PostConstruct
   public void init(){
      userLists = ss.getUsers();
   }
}
```

> What I want to know is how to make the role name shown in my place of
>   the ID

Huh ? I guess you want this :

```
<h:dataTable value="#{mybean.userLists}" var="user">
    <h:column>
      #{user.role.name} 
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

In your entities you must have a relationship between the two. Probably `@ManyToOne`

> and make that field a List showing only possible roles (which are all
>   the columns of the Roles table)

Same idea, get your list from db in the `init` method:

```
roleList = aService.getRoles();
```

Then You want to display those in a list ? I guess you meant a [selectOneMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info). Follow the link the tutorial is well explained.