# CDI interceptor not fired when JSF managed bean method is invoked

Tags: jsf, cdi, interceptor

This my interceptor study case, but it doesn't fire.

**The annotation for interceptor**

```
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;
import java.lang.annotation.Inherited;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import javax.interceptor.InterceptorBinding;

@Inherited
@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, TYPE})
public @interface LogInterceptor {
}
```

**The Implementation for interceptor**

```
import javax.annotation.Priority;
import javax.interceptor.Interceptor;
import javax.interceptor.InvocationContext;

@Interceptor
@LogInterceptor
@Priority(Interceptor.Priority.APPLICATION)
public class LogInterceptorImpl {
    @AroundInvoke
    public Object log(InvocationContext context) {
        Object o = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("START");
            o = context.proceed();
            System.out.println("END");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return o;
    }
}
```

**The controller**

```
import modelo.Post;
import interceptor.LogInterceptor;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean(name = "postController")
@SessionScoped
public class PostController implements Serializable {

    private List<Post> items = null;
    private Post selected;

    public PostController() {
        MyFacade facade = new MyFacade();
        items = facade.getItems();
    }

    @LogInterceptor
    public List<Post> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
}
```

**The glassfish log**

```
Informações:   EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd
Informações:   file:/C:/Users/f9921257/Documents/NetBeansProjects/estudo/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/_estudoPU login successful
Informações:   Portable JNDI names for EJB PostFacade: [java:global/estudo/PostFacade!facade.PostFacade, java:global/estudo/PostFacade]
Informações:   Portable JNDI names for EJB CategoriaFacade: [java:global/estudo/CategoriaFacade!facade.CategoriaFacade, java:global/estudo/CategoriaFacade]
Informações:   WELD-000900: 2.2.2 (Final)
WARN:   WELD-001700: Interceptor annotation class javax.ejb.PostActivate not found, interception based on it is not enabled
WARN:   WELD-001700: Interceptor annotation class javax.ejb.PrePassivate not found, interception based on it is not enabled
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.gf.cdi.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
Informações:   Inicializando Mojarra 2.2.7 ( 20140610-1547 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.7@13362) para o contexto '/estudo'
Informações:   Monitoring jndi:/server/estudo/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
Informações:   Running on PrimeFaces 5.0
Informações:   Loading application [estudo] at [/estudo]
Informações:   estudo was successfully deployed in 13.298 milliseconds.
```

The marks "START" and "END" put on LogInterceptorImpl does not appear in the log file. Why they doesn't fire?

Comment: Have you checked that System.out is set to output to the server logs? Try adding another System.out in the Controller to verify this.

Comment: Yes a System.out on the controller was fired but the interceptor's not.

Comment: Your interceptor method is not annotated witg @aroundinvoke

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `@javax.inject.Named` annotation instead of `@ManagedBean`:

```
@Named("postController")
@SessionScoped
public class PostController
```

Also add @AroundInvoke to mark the interceptor method:

```
@Interceptor
@LogInterceptor
public class LogInterceptorImpl {
    @AroundInvoke
    public Object log(InvocationContext context) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And the last step, you need to enable the interceptor in beans.xml, otherwise the interceptor would be ignored:

**beans.xml**

```
<beans>
   <interceptors>
      <class>com.nameofyourpackage.LogInterceptorImpl </class>
   </interceptors>
</beans>
```

**Explanation for using @Named instead of @ManagedBean**

Both annotations mean essentially the same - they give a textual name to a bean, so that it may be accessed in a JSF page. However, beans marked `@ManagedBean` are created by the JSF subsystem and CDI annotations are ignored (such as SessionScoped or interceptor qualifiers, such as your LogInterceptor). Beans marked `@Named` can take full advantage of CDI, while you cannot use JSF specific annotations, like `@ManagedProperty` (you should use @Inject with CDI). This is not a problem as `@ManagedProperty` and `@ManagedBean` are both deprecated and there is always a way how to accomplish the same with CDI. This is discussed in more detail here: [Backing beans (@ManagedBean) or CDI Beans (@Named)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347374/backing-beans-managedbean-or-cdi-beans-named)