# Equivalent of JSP scriptlet method call in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets, scriptlet

I need to convert a JSP file to an equivalent JSF file. The JSP is as follows:

Step 1: Class Import:

```
<%@ page import="org.keycloak.constants.ServiceUrlConstants" %>
<%@ page import="org.keycloak.common.util.KeycloakUriBuilder" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
```

Step 2: Define a variable:

```
<%
        String logoutUri = KeycloakUriBuilder.fromUri("/auth").path(ServiceUrlConstants.TOKEN_SERVICE_LOGOUT_PATH).queryParam("redirect_uri", "/customer-portal").build("demo").toString();  %>
```

Step 3: Then refers to this variable:

```
<a href="<%=logoutUri%>">logout</a>
```

The imported library is an external library into the project. In JSF, I know how to do Step 3. But I don't know how to import the classes in Step 1 and how to define a variable as shown in Step 2 in JSF.

Is there an equivalent way of performing Step 1-3 in JSF? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call Methods directly in JSF or create variables, therefore you don't need imports.
The only way is to use EL-Expressions. 
Since calling static Methods is not possible with EL, you'll have to create yourself a Bean, that makes the call of `KeycloakUriBuilder.fromUri...`
With a Named Bean you call its Methods:

Example:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
//This Bean is available by default under the Name 'myBean', you can change it in the @Named Annotation if desired
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable { 

    public String myMethod(String inupt){
        return "Hello " + input;
    }
}
```

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" >
<head></head>
<body>
<h:outputText value ="#{myBean.myMethod('world')}"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Will give you this HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head></head>
<body>Hello world
</body>
</html>
```

The preferred way to show Something on the page is to use getters and setters, if you have a field with getter and Setter

```
private String name;
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

You can just use

```
#{myBean.name}
```

JSF will call the getter if it needs the value (for output) or call the Setter if there is a value to set (from input-fields)

The `<%@ page session="false" %>` is also neither needed nor possible.
In JSF the Bean has a Scope, this example with `RequestScoped` should be a good match for `<%@ page session="false" %>` - a Request Scoped Bean lives only for one Request, after that the Bean is disposed. There are many other scopes, e.g. `@SessionScoped` (from `javax.enterprise.context`) for a Bean that lives as  long as the Session is active.

As mentioned by another User, those Scopes exists in the CDI-Variant (Package `javax.enterprise.context`) and a JSF-variant (package `javax.faces.bean`). You should use the CDI-Variant, since the JSF-Variant might be deprecated soon (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4347707/5072526)).

Explanation of the Scopes see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7031941/5072526).

Comment: @hinneLins, Got it. Then what about the "<%@ page session="false" %>" in JSP? How to realize this in JSF?

Comment: Please ask new questions in new Questions.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the info.