# update from p:commandButton doesn't work

Tags: jsf, primefaces, cdi

I search for someone who can help me out with this "small" problem, I searched for hours. The code below is "broken down", so the real application is huge, I can't move technology at the moment.

So I have primefaces 5.0.10 and MyFaces 2.0.3 and I have to deal with that.

Here's an XHTML:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
template="../index.xhtml">
<ui:define name="title">Keyboard Bean Test</ui:define>

<ui:define name="content">
    <h1>Keyboard Bean Test</h1>

    <h:form id="myform">
        <p:panel header="KeyboardBean">
            <p:keyboard value="#{keyboardBean.value}"></p:keyboard>
        </p:panel>

        <h:outputText id="myOutput" value="#{keyboardBean.value}"></h:outputText> <br /><br />

        <p:commandButton value="Setzen" update="myOutput"></p:commandButton>
    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

And here's my **KeyboardBean.java**

```
package de.lippoliv.test.primefaces.beans;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named("keyboardBean")
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class KeyboardBean {

    private String value;

    public String getValue () {
        System.out.println("KeyboardBean::reading value: " + value);

        return value;
    }

    public void setValue (String newValue) {
        System.out.println("KeyboardBean::write value: " + newValue);

        value = newValue;
    }

}
```

What I would like to to: Update the outputText on pressing the commandButton. QUIET SO SIMPLE!

In the real application the use-case is different, but for start figuring out why it doesn't work in real application, I decided to break it down to this simple think and then make it (step by step) more like the real application.

Whatever: This doesn't work. The outputText just refresh after page-load. I tryed a lot till now, nothing worked. Just switching from MyFaces to original JSF, but that is (as I wrote) not possible for me at the moment.

Hopefully someone can help me out here.

**update 1**

Here's the Ouput of console:

```
26.02.2016 11:58:58 org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.Tomcat7AnnotationLifecycleProvider newInstance
INFO: Creating instance of de.rac.oliverlippert.test.primefaces.beans.MenuBean
26.02.2016 11:58:58 org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.Tomcat7AnnotationLifecycleProvider newInstance
INFO: Creating instance of de.rac.oliverlippert.test.primefaces.beans.KeyboardBean
KeyboardBean::reading value: null
KeyboardBean::reading value: null
KeyboardBean::reading value: null
KeyboardBean::reading value: null
26.02.2016 11:59:01 org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.Tomcat7AnnotationLifecycleProvider newInstance
INFO: Creating instance of de.rac.oliverlippert.test.primefaces.beans.KeyboardBean
26.02.2016 11:59:01 javax.faces.validator._ExternalSpecifications isUnifiedELAvailable
INFO: MyFaces Unified EL support enabled
KeyboardBean::reading value: null
KeyboardBean::write value: sdf
```

Very interessting: After pressing the commandButton once, the Beans will not be called again...

Also I modifyed my bean, it now starts with

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class KeyboardBean {
    ...
}
```

AND also I modifyed my "update" to use the whole id:

```
<p:commandButton value="Setzen" update=":myform:myOutput"></p:commandButton>
```

All that doesn't change a thing :/

FireFox throws one JS error on pressing the button:

```
TypeError: f is null (javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js.xhtml?ln=primfaces&v=5.0 row 2 col 6868)
```

Thanks for any reply

**update 2**
OK breaking it down to this XHTML, it work:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
>

<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>Primefaces Test</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h1>Keyboard Bean Test</h1>

    <h:form id="myform">
        <h:panelGrid id="grid" cellpadding="5" columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px">
            <p:panel header="KeyboardBean">
                <p:keyboard value="#{keyboardBean.value}"></p:keyboard>
            </p:panel>
            <h:outputText id="myOutput" styleClass="update" value="#{keyboardBean.value}"></h:outputText>

            <h:outputText id="myOutput2" styleClass="update" value="#{keyboardBean.value}"></h:outputText>
            <h:outputText id="myOutput3" styleClass="update" value="#{keyboardBean.value}"></h:outputText>
        </h:panelGrid>

        <p:commandButton value="Setzen" update="@(.update)"></p:commandButton>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Now I can move forward step by step. Thanks for all :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Backing beans (@ManagedBean) or CDI Beans (@Named)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347374/backing-beans-managedbean-or-cdi-beans-named)

Comment: Your title is very wrong. It suggests it works with PrimeFaces 5.1 or with Mojarra or even myfaces 2.1. And very remarkable that a question like this has 2 upvotes and 2 **favorites even** in 2 hours. Very suspicious

Comment: Hey Kukeltje, I specifyed Version-Numbers because I have to use those Numbers. I haven't tryed newer Versions because I can't migrate. One fav is from me, the other I don't know.

Comment: Put them in your question, not title

Comment: Please take a step back from development... You annotations are wrong... create an [mcve] (e.g. dropping the template)

Comment: @Kukeltje OK will give a try to get less code. MyFaces (Maven Dependency org.apache.myfaces.core) indeed should stay in title, because using original (Maven Dependency com.sun.faces) will work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to remove @ManagedBean annotation and import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped instead of javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped?

It seems to me that at this moment you are mixing CDI beans with Backing beans. Details and differences are provided [at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347374/backing-beans-managedbean-or-cdi-beans-named)

Comment: Please mark the question as a duplicate of the link you posted.

Comment: @user1072089 thanks for your answer. I read this post. I understand that mixing CDI beans with Backing beans is not good. I modifyed my bean just using "Named" "SessionScoped", but it still does not change anything.

Comment: @user1072089 I simplifyed my XHTML as described in "update 2" and then backported to my original bean, it doesn't work. Then I did what described in your link and now it works. Also JAVA stops generating new beans each refresh and use the old one. Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your Problem:

### Bean

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean {

    private String testValue = "a";

    public void setTestValue(final String testValue) {
        this.testValue = testValue;
    }

    public String getTestValue() {
        return testValue;
    }

    public void testAction() {
        setTestValue("b");
    }
}
```

### View

```
<h:outputText id="testId" value="#{roleEditController.testValue}" />
<p:commandButton update="testId" action="#{roleEditController.testAction}" />
```

But in my case it is working :/

- Don't you get any javascript or java errors?
- Did you try to use the absolute id to update the component?

You can find the absolute id if you inspect the page with your Browser:

```
<span id="form:testId">a</span>
```

In this case the absolute id would be ***:form:testId***

Comment: The other 'answer' contains the reason why it most likely works for you

Comment: @71m024 thanks for answer. See my update, it still doesn't work