# Converter in jsf not work

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, converters

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="tag1" value="#{attachmentManagement.tag1}" converter="#{stringFilterConverter}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{attachmentManagement.tag1List}" var="tag1" itemLabel="#{not empty tag1.value ? tag1.value : '无'}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:commandButton value="button" actionListener="#{attachmentManagement.someFuction()}"/>
```

When I click the button, this exception was throwed:

```
javax.faces.component.UpdateModelException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert com.bolan.fzsystem.appserver.view.model.StringFilter@17dbb2e of type class java.lang.String to class com.bolan.fzsystem.appserver.view.model.StringFilter
....
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert com.bolan.fzsystem.appserver.view.model.StringFilter@17dbb2e of type class java.lang.String to class com.bolan.fzsystem.appserver.view.model.StringFilter
....
```

stringFilterConverter and someFunction is not called at all.
Since I have set a converter, why jsf not use it and use toString() to update the value.

My converter implementation is a CDI bean. I found the solution. I change the scope of converter from default to application scope. And now converter works. But why?

This is my converter implementation:

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped //change scope from default to this
public class StringFilterConverter implements Converter, Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = -6691961589607931061L;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
            return ValueFilter.UNDEFINE;
        }
        return JSON.parseObject(value, new TypeReference<String>() {});
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        ValueFilter<String> filter = (ValueFilter<String>) value;
        return JSON.toJSONString(filter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read this very interesting post [CDI Bean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347374/backing-beans-managedbean-or-cdi-beans-named)

Answer (score 0):

In your code snippet you define converter as `converter="#{stringFilterConverter}"` however I think that you shouldn't wrap the name of your converter with EL expression syntax, so proper usage of converter should be :

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="tag1" value="#{attachmentManagement.tag1} converter="stringFilterConverter"/>
```

(of course I assume that your converter implementation class has annotation `@FacesConverter("stringFilterConverter")`)

Comment: My converter implementation is a CDI bean. I found the solution. I change the scope of converter from default to application scope. And now converter works. But why?

Comment: Could you update your answer with converter implementation?